# How to unblock Wifi

Tags: wireless, 22.04

Recently I have a problem relating to wifi on Ubuntu. After a few day using Ubuntu, the toggle for Wifi does appear but I can't swipe it or clicking the turn on to show the list of available wifi for me to connect. I have tried with rfkill, ncmli radio wifi on but it does not work. Can anyone help me with this problem, I would be grateful.

[Wifi on button does appear but I can't click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7USa6.png)

[Wifi toggle I can't swipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmVmX.png)

Comment: Please show us the complete output of `rfkill`

Comment: `sudo nmcli radio wifi on'